# Can't Import Functions from Imported Classes

Tags: typescript, nestjs

**file1:**

```
export default class Functions {
    async functionOne(sessionID: string): Promise<void> {
        console.log(sessionID);
    }
}
```

**file2:**

```
import Functions from './file1';

Functions.functionOne('test');
```

This gives error of:

> error TS2339: Property 'functionOne' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   Functions'.

I'm trying to call a function from another file. I've tried to create new instance of class but it does produce the same error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make you method a static one if you want to access it without instantiating your class.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer that I'm pretty much a beginner with typescript, but I would just export the function itself if that's all you would need the class for.